# why when accessing data from the base class from a derived class does it return nonsense (pointer data i think)

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance

I am making a collision detection system for a text based game using co-ordinates. I am trying to retrieve the x and y positions of my player and an array of monsters. The co-ordinates are held in a bass class Character. when i try to retrieve the data it returns Xpos    -858993460 which i am assuming is comming from the pointers i am using.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int MON_SIZE = 10;
monster* monArr[MON_SIZE];
player player1;
bool collision();

int main(){

void initialise();
player1.moveChar(3, 6);
bool temp;
temp = collision();

if (temp = true){
    cout << endl << "collision detected" << endl;
}

        system("pause");
        return 0;
}


void initialise()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {

        int inx = rand() % 9;
        int iny = rand() % 9;

        monArr[i] = new monster();
        monArr[i]->moveChar(inx, iny);
    }
}

bool collision()
{
    bool collision;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int mx, my, px, py;
        monArr[i]->getPos(mx, my);
        player1.getPos(px, py);

        if (mx == px && my == py)
        {
            collision = true;
            cout << endl << mx << " " << my << endl;
        }else collision = false;
    }
    return collision;
}


#pragma once
#include "character.h"
class player :
    public character
{
private:

public:
    player();
    ~player();
};


#pragma once
#include "character.h"
class monster :
    public character
{
public:
    monster();
    ~monster();
private:

};


#include "character.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

character::character()
{
    xpos = 0;
    ypos = 0;
}


character::~character()
{
}


void character::moveChar(int Xpos, int Ypos)
{
    xpos = Xpos;
    ypos = Ypos;
}

void character::printPos(){
    cout << "Position: " << xpos << " . " << ypos << endl;
}

void character::getPos(int& Xpos, int& Ypos){
    Xpos= xpos;
    Ypos= ypos;
}


#pragma once
class character
{
public:
    character();
    ~character();
    void moveChar(int Xpos, int Ypos);
    void printPos();
    void getPos(int& Xpos, int& Ypos);
protected:
    int xpos;
    int ypos;
};
```

Comment: First possible error: `void initialize();` declares a function named `initialize`. If you want to call a function named `initialize`, you need to say `initialize();`.

Comment: Second possible error: `if (temp = true)`. You probably wanted to say `if (temp == true)`. This by the way is redundant and confusing. Say `if (temp)`

Comment: As a side note, your getter is not that intuitive. I would suggest you create a struct Point { int x, int y, Point(int xc, int yc) : x(xc), y(yc) {} } and return Point when calling a getter. You can always use references / pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main(){
    void initialise();
    ...
```

The above does not call the function initialize. Although you did not post that function, I suppose it initializes your arrays and variables... Write instead:

```
int main(){
    initialise();
    ...
```

And move the definition of initialize() to before main, or at least put a declaration of its prototype.

Comment: @anon Plz re-read the edit. Move the definition of initialize() to before main, or at least put a declaration of its prototype.

Comment: initialized it above the main function before calling it. its working now thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your charactoer::getPos function to this:

```
void character::getPos(int& Xpos, int& Ypos){
    Xpos = xpos;
    Ypos = ypos;
}
```

The statement Xpos *= xpos is equivalent to Xpos = Xpos * xpos.  This is not what you want, especially since your Xpos argument is not initialize.

Comment: First-chance exception at 0x00CB5A89 in week 5 prograqmming.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x00CB5A89 in week 5 prograqmming.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

The thread 0x2cc0 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 0x2528 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 0x2964 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 0x2c54 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The program '[7232] week 5 prograqmming.exe' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).

Comment: You will have to step through a debugger.  Otherwise post a complete example.  Your posted code is not complete.